# How to set a field to keep a row unique in lucene?

Tags: lucene, uniqueidentifier

My app generates unique id for each row to index in lucene and save to database.
One sutation is if there is and row have the same id,I want to update it,not insert an new row and index.

How to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of the [IndexWrite#updateDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#updateDocument%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20org.apache.lucene.document.Document%29) method. The first argument is the term that must be unique in your index.

For example,

```
String id = "42";
Document doc = new Document();
Field field = new Field("id", id, Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
doc.add(field);

indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("id", id), doc);
```

will ensure that `doc` is the only document with id 42 in your index.

Comment: If the id does not exists,will it insert?

Comment: Yes. The documentation states "Updates a document by first deleting the document(s) containing term and then adding the new document." so in the particular case where no document was indexed with the same ID before, no document will be deleted.