# How to set unique document id in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

The answer given at [How to set a field to keep a row unique in lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595057/how-to-set-a-field-to-keep-a-row-unique-in-lucene) is deprecated. So How do I do this presently?

Also can I search by said document id? as a StringField (i.e. exact match)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the `Field` declaration, since `IndexWriter.updateDocument` really hasn't changed a great deal and is not deprecated.

If you don't need to search with it, use [`StoredField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StoredField.html):

```
Field field = new StoredField("myfield", "content");
```

If you do, use [`StringField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html):

```
Field field = new StringField("myfield", "content", Field.Store.YES);
```

Comment: I am referring to the line `Field field = new Field("id", id, Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED);`

Comment: Right.  Like I said, use StringField.

Comment: I see. That makes sense I suppose.