# Updating Lucene payloads without a full re-index

Tags: lucene

In Lucene, I'm using payloads to store information for each token in a document (a float value in my case).  From time to time, those payloads may need to be updated.  If I know the docID, termID, offset, etc., is there any way for me to update the payloads in place without having to re-index the whole document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no aware of any Lucene API to support this, even an "update" operation under the hood is executed as a "delete" and "add" add operation.

A workaround that will require more storage, but reduces IO and latency could be to store the whole source of a document either in the Lucene index itself or a dedicated data store on the same node as the Lucene index. Then you still could send only the updated payload info to your application, to get your document updated. But still the whole document needs to be re-indexed.

See also [How to set a field to keep a row unique in lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595057/how-to-set-a-field-to-keep-a-row-unique-in-lucene)